# Save kableExtra table to .png with save_kable() is not working in R 4.3.2. Error in sub(file, "", filename) : invalid regular expression

Tags: r, kableextra

I am trying to save a kableExtra html table to .png format in R.  This worked smoothly for previous versions of R, but I recently started getting an error message I cannot understand after switching to version 4.3.2.  There are no regular expressions in the contents of the table so I am not sure what to make of this.

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling kableExtra and webshot2, to no avail.

Here is an example:

---

```
library(kableExtra)

df <- data.frame(x = c(1:10), y = c(11:20))

tab <- kbl(df) |> kable_classic()

save_kable(tab, "tab.png")
```

---

*This should save a .png image of the table, but instead I get the following error message:*

Warning: TRE pattern compilation error 'Invalid back reference'Error in sub(file, "", filename) :
invalid regular expression 'C:\Users\ECS155\AppData\Local\Temp\2\Rtmp0SBfQp\tab34a035bd7a3f.html', reason 'Invalid back reference'

*with full traceback: *

Error in sub(file, "", filename) :
invalid regular expression 'C:\Users\ECS155\AppData\Local\Temp\2\Rtmp0SBfQp\tab34a035bd7a3f.html', reason 'Invalid back reference'

7.
sub(file, "", filename)

6.
file_url(x)

5.
FUN(X[[i]], ...)

4.
vapply(url, function(x) {
if (!is_url(x)) {
file_url(x)
} ...

3.
webshot2::webshot(file_temp_html, file, ...)

2.
save_kable_html(x, file, bs_theme, self_contained, extra_dependencies,
density, ...)

1.
save_kable(tab, "tab.png")

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: What version of {webshot2} are you using? Try `utils::packageVersion("webshot2")` and report the output.

Comment: I have version 0.1.1 of webshot2 installed.

Answer (score 0):

Updates exist for {webshot2} (v0.1.1) that have not yet been pushed to CRAN.

Specifically [this](https://github.com/rstudio/webshot2/commit/37a47513d86768fb2f0865d3ec8e70ee7b0df1b8) change might solve your issue.

Try installing the DEV version of {webshot2} (v0.1.1.9000) from GitHub with

```
devtools::install_github("rstudio/webshot2")
```

or

```
remotes::install_github("rstudio/webshot2")
```

or

```
pak::pkg_install("rstudio/webshot2")
```

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I tried this but still have the same error, now with webshot2 version 0.1.1.9.

Comment: Darn, I was sure this was the issue. FWIW: I was unable to reproduce your error on Windows 10 with R v4.3.2 and kableExtra v1.4.0.2 and webshot2 v0.1.1.9000.

Comment: I am using kableExtra v1.4.0 (from utils::packageVersion("kableExtra").  I will try the developer version of kableExtra (v1.4.0.2 ?).  Also, I am working on a virtual machine where I do not have administrator access, so I think there are some issues with updating the other dependencies that could be responsible.